# Displaying more than one messages on Label together in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

NET actually am creating a form in which I in need to perform validation of three textboxes and display the message on single label I created code for all the three textbox for validation but when i am calling it on validation button it is executing only the last called function please help i want it to display messages from all the three textboxes together on label

```
sub ValidatingBox1 ()
if Textbox1.Text = "" Then
label1.text = "Box 1 is blank"
elseif textbox1.text > 10 Then
label1.text = "Box 1 is not in range"
else: label1.text = "Box 1 is valid"
endif
end sub

sub ValidatingBox2 ()
if Textbox2.Text = "" Then
label1.text = "Box 2 is blank"
elseif textbox2.text > 10 Then
label1.text = "Box 2 is not in range"
else: label1.text = "Box 2 is valid"
endif
end sub


sub ValidatingBox3 ()
if Textbox3.Text = "" Then
label1.text = "Box 3 is blank"
elseif textbox3.text > 10 Then
label1.text = "Box 3 is not in range"
else: label1.text = "Box 3 is valid"
endif
end sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

call ValidatingBox1()
call ValidatingBox2()
call ValidatingBox3()

end sub
```

Comment: `label1.text &= "the new message to add"`

Comment: I am sorry to bother you but am new to .Net can you please elaborate this

Comment: your procedures are assigning new text to the label.  if you want the label to accumulate text, you need to concatenate the message (add to it).  leave ValidatingBox1 alone so it clears the old message then concatenate using `&=` for the messages

Comment: It is pretty pointless, everybody hates the "you are a complete fail" notification.  Just let the user work on *one* problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the message like this

```
Label1.Text = Label1.text & "Message "
```

It will come out like this

Box 1 is blank Box 2 is valid Box 3 is not in range

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you overriding the message will make that it returns only the last one. Please try the below;

```
sub ValidatingBox1 ()

if StringIsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text) Then

' Concatenate error message with message already in label
label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 1 is blank")
elseif textbox1.text > 10 Then
label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 1 is not in range")
else: label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 1 is valid")
endif
end sub

sub ValidatingBox2 ()
if StringIsNullOrEmpty(Textbox2.Text) Then
label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 2 is blank")
elseif textbox2.text > 10 Then
label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 2 is not in range")
else: label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 2 is valid")
endif

end sub


sub ValidatingBox3 ()
if StringIsNullOrEmpty(Textbox3.Text) Then

label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 3 is blank")
elseif textbox3.text > 10 Then
label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 3 is not in range")
else: label1.text = String.Concat(textbox1.text, "Box 3 is valid")
endif
end sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

' Initialise label
label1.text = ""
call ValidatingBox1()
call ValidatingBox2()
call ValidatingBox3()

end sub
```